# Trouble with cascading in Active Record models

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have these active record models in my application

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :albums, :dependent => :delete_all, autosave: true
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :album_artist
   has_many :tracks, :dependent => :delete_all, autosave: true
   has_many :covers, :dependent => :delete_all, autosave: true
   belongs_to :artist
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :album
end

class Cover < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :album
end
```

I'm trying, in my application, when i delete an Artist, his albums and, in consequence, the tracks and covers of his albums, get all deleted, in a cascade reaction.

The way it's implemented today, when i delete the Artist, only the Album is deleted too, leaving orphan records in my database.

Am i doin' anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `:dependent => :delete_all` you need to configure:

```
:dependent => :destroy_all
```

Because `delete` will just delete all its associated objects directly from the database without calling their destroy method (what break cascading).

You might want to read 4.1.2.4 in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference